# Sort YouTube video comments by rating

Tags: youtube

Since most YouTube comments are noise, is there a way to order them by rating on the video page? The two top comments seem to be shown, but I often want to see more.

I'm adding another bounty, since the question is almost a year old and my current solution is simply just reading the top-two comments. Greasemonkey scripts, Firefox/Chromium plugins and sites with embedded players would all be welcomed as solutions.

Comment: Any thoughts on why Youtube are (evidently) making sure their built-in Sort does not work as expected in terms of sorting comments by rating? It just seems very strange that Chrome extensions are needed to provide such a basic function. Do people think it likely that Youtube are just trying to get people to spend more time on site, leafing through hundreds of comments before (manually/visually) finding those that are top-voted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just installed [Youtube Comment Retriever](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gkpnfhfacokjdleldlafjleaannkodmp). It is a Chrome extension. When you watch YouTube video, you can open side panel, where you will see comments sorted from highest rated.

I haven't found similar add-on for Firefox, but there are some other nice plugins (eg. YouTube Comment Snob) that can at least filter undesirable comments.

Answer (score 3):

So far, [no way](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/youtube/thread?tid=2473c5a8e4d47122&hl=en) to do it within YouTube alone. There might be a Greasemonkey script able to do that, but I couldn't find any. [Maybe someone can make one based on others](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/79516). Meanwhile, in case you're using Google Chrome or Firefox, you can find in [OpinionCloud](http://www.webis.de/research/projects/opinioncloud) a much better idea on how to handle the endless comments.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at [Sort Youtube Comments by Rating](http://userscripts.org/topics/97021)